# How to access a field in a different class without static? (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, static, field

I'm creating a battle sim. I've got a Attack class and a warrior Class.

```
public class Attack {

    private String name;
    private int points;

    public Attack(String name, int points) {
        this.name= name;
        this.points =points;

    }

    //getters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return ("Name of the attack = " + name + " damage = " + points) ;

    }

}
```

Since the warriors with have different attacks, I can't use static as it will override the previous attack. Snippet of Monster class:

```
        public Attack[] getAttacks() {
        return attacks;
    }
public void attack(String attackname, Warrior otherWarrior){
// How would I access the attack from the class?

}
```

How would I be able to access the Attack fields?
Thanks.

Comment: **How would I be able to access the Attack fields?** you have `getters` of your fiels, don't you? just use it to get your values. `attack.getName()`

Comment: Could you post your definition of the Warrior class too? Your question is a little confusing without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as you can access the instance methods of `this` `Monster` class, you can access the instance methods of your `Warrior` class:

```
public class Monster {
    Attack[] attacks;
    // ...

    public Attack[] getAttacks(){
        return attacks;
    }

    public void attack(String attackname, Warrior otherWarrior){
        Attack[] monsterAttacks = this.getAttacks();

        // Assuming Warrior has the method `getAttacks()`
        Attack[] warriorAttacks = otherWarrior.getAttacks();

        // ...
    }
}

public class Warrior {
    Attack[] attacks;
    // ...

    public Attack[] getAttacks() {
        return attacks;
    }
}
```